# Remove date in dataframe in range of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I got two dataframes. The first contain a date, an sensor_id and contain some values. The other one contain date, sensor_id and got a start and end datetime values.

The first dataframe is the dataframe with the datas I'm working on. The second one is a list of time period when I know that the data is not accurate and I want to remove all the datas in the first dataframe based on the period of the second dataframe.

Until now I merged "outer" the two dataframe and filter. But now the dataframe is really too big and I don't have enough memory to handle it.

So I'm looking for a better solution.

My fist df :

```
     sensor_id       date           value
        8         2016-03-30         0
        8         2016-03-31         2
        8         2016-03-31         4
        8         2016-03-31         6
        8         2016-03-31         0
```

The list of alarm :

```
 sensor_id     status  __start__    __end__
       119  RECOVERED 2019-02-26 2019-02-26
       112  RECOVERED 2019-02-26 2019-02-26
        38  RECOVERED 2019-02-26 2019-02-26
         8  RECOVERED 2016-03-25 2016-03-30
       123  RECOVERED 2019-02-26 2019-02-26
```

Final df :

```
     sensor_id       date           value
        8         2016-03-31         2
        8         2016-03-31         4
        8         2016-03-31         6
        8         2016-03-31         0
```

Because I got in the list of alarm a period for this sensor_id from 2016-03-25 to 2016-03-30 So I want to remove in the final df the data between 2016-03-25 to 2016-03-30.

I would not prefer to iter over the second df to remove data from the first one.

Hope this is clear. Many thx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

We could `merge` first

```
df=df1.merge(df2,on='sensor_id').query('date>__end__ or date <__start__')
   sensor_id        date  value     status   __start__     __end__
1          8  2016-03-31      2  RECOVERED  2016-03-25  2016-03-30
2          8  2016-03-31      4  RECOVERED  2016-03-25  2016-03-30
3          8  2016-03-31      6  RECOVERED  2016-03-25  2016-03-30
4          8  2016-03-31      0  RECOVERED  2016-03-25  2016-03-30
```

Comment: hello, memory usage is exactly the same here as we cross all the data of the two dataframe.

Comment: @OlivierAudry do it by chunk , you can chunk the df2 row by row filter the df1

Comment: indeed, but it's 5 times longer. I guess I have to make a choice. RAM or execution time. I was hopping that another could exist